# No layout when returning new ViewModel?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm upgrading my app from ZF-1.12 to ZF-2.4.

I' have this login controller:

```
class LoginController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->layout('login/layout');
        return new ViewModel(array(
                'form' => 'some-form-object',
               ));
    }

}
```

The thing is, the view seems to be rendered without the selected layout.

However, when I comment out the 'return new ViewModel'.. everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 'form' is sensitive word, when changing the var name - it worked.